# adding copy of array to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to add a copy of an array to another array with array.slice(), but when I update the original, it updates the copy that I added.  How can I add a copy that isn't altered when the original is altered?

I've tried using result.unshift[...curRow], and result.unshift(curRow.slice()) when I add

```js
function game(n) {
    var result = [];
    let row1=[[1, 2]];
    for (var i=1;i<n;i++){
      var cur = row1[i];
      var prev = row1[i - 1];
      row1.push([prev[0] + 1, prev[1] + 1]);
    }
    result.push(row1.slice());
    let curRow = row1.slice();
    for (var i=1;i<n;i++){
      for (var j = 0; j<curRow.length ;j++){
          curRow[j][1]++;
      }
      result.unshift(curRow.slice());
      console.log('curRow =',curRow);
      console.log('result = ', result)
   }
   console.log('result = ', result)
   return result
}

game(3);
```

This is my current output:
'result ='[ [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 4 ] ] ]
'result = '[ [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 3, 5 ] ], [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 3, 5 ] ] ]
'result = '[ [ [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 5 ], [ 3, 6 ] ], [ [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 5 ], [ 3, 6 ] ], [ [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 5 ], [ 3, 6 ] ] ]

I want the result array to contain each iteration of the curRow array, instead of just having copies of the latest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, objects/arrays, also known as non-primitive types, are given a reference, rather than value. Therefore, this particular reference points to the object's location in the memory. That variable you are working with has a 'reference' rather than containing an actual 'value'. This is why it is mutated when you use it on the `game()` function.

To work with that, you should create a [shallow copy](https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c) of that array, before making any manipulation/mutation to it.

```
const copy = originalArray.map(element => ({...element}));
```

Now, all changes to the `copy` array will not be applied to `originalArray`.

Comment: You can also do `const copy = [...originalArray];`

Comment: @TehSoTo Yes! For the OP's scenario, `const copy = [...originalArray]` would be sufficient. Thank you!

Comment: I've tried both [...originalArray] and originalArray.slice() in the above code, but it still updates all the previously added elements and makes them the same.  Take a look at the the output and see.

Answer (score 0):

Because in Javascript Arrays are handled by reference, when you reasign an array to a new variable, **the new variable only holds a reference to the original array**. Any alteration on the original array will be reflected in any of its instances/references (beucause they are essentially the same object).

Since the ES6 version of the standard we have `Array.from()` to **perform copies or duplicates of the contents of an Array.** 
It's my favorite way to go, is fast, safe and readable.

> The Array.from() method creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an array-like or iterable object. **Extended documentation** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Check the example :

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5];
let b = Array.from(a);

// modify first array to test
a[0] = 666;
// output second array to check
console.log(b)
// [1,2,3,4,5]  OK!
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this concept:

```
firstArray=firstArray.concat(...secondArray);
```